# Scrapy, crawl data by onclick

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to extract the title and the pdf link of each paper in this link: https://iclr.cc/Conferences/2019/Schedule?type=Poster

[image]

My code is here

```
class ICLRCrawler(Spider):
    name = "ICLRCrawler"
    allowed_domains = ["iclr.cc"]
    start_urls = ["https://iclr.cc/Conferences/2019/Schedule?type=Poster", ]

    def parse(self, response):
        papers = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/div[@class="paper"]')
        titles = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="maincard_704"]/div[3]')
        links = Selector(response).xpath('//*[@id="maincard_704"]/div[6]/a[2]')
        for title, link in zip(titles, links):
            item = PapercrawlerItem()
            item['title'] = title.xpath('text()').extract()[0]
            item['pdf'] = link.xpath('/@href').extract()[0]
            item['sup'] = ''
            yield item
```

However, it seems that it is not easy to get the title and link of each paper. Here, how can I change the code to get the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use much simpler approach:

```
def parse(self, response):

    for poster in response.xpath('//div[starts-with(@id, "maincard_")]'):
        item = PapercrawlerItem()
        item["title"] = poster.xpath('.//div[@class="maincardBody"]/text()[1]').get()
        item["pdf"] = poster.xpath('.//a[@title="PDF"]/@href').get()

        yield item
```

Comment: Your answer is really great. Getting to know what `xpath` should I extract is hard, how can I better understand it?

Comment: @GoingMyWay you're using ancient style code (`Selector`). Where did you get it? I recommend you to read Scrapy documentation with nice ready to use examples.

Comment: Hi, I learned Scarpy 4 years ago, the code is my old code. Thank you, I will read Scrapy's document.

Answer (score 0):

you have to replace `Extract()[0]` with `get_attribute('href')`

Comment: `links` is empty. So I think it is not this issue.

Comment: this is for extracting the link :-driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="maincard_704"]/div[6]/a[2]').get_attribute('href')
this is for extracting the title name:-driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="maincard_676"]/div[3]').text